Azure ADO not giving details error message for PySpark Unit Testing
I am in the process of creating sample PySpark ADO build.
The build includes code coverage and UnitTesting.
Below are my issues.
the unit testing is working fine in the local.
But during the ADO build it's just giving generic ERROR statement and not even printing the print statement.
(4 durations < 0.005s hidden.  Use -vv to show these durations.)
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_pyspark.py::test_single_space
ERROR test_validCount.py::test_row_count
============================== 2 errors in 0.35s ===============================
 
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Unit test & Code Coverage

Tried adding print statements and checked ,whether the file is been picked or not.

Glad to see you in Stack Overflow! Please show the Unit test script details, pipeline yaml and other info about how to reproduce the issue . Please check the link how to ask. In addition, since it works on the local, please try to set it as self-hosted agent for a test, will it work?
